# How to simply multiply two columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiplication

My input is

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(1,2,4,8)
df<-data.frame(cbind(a,b))
```

My output should be

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(1,2,4,8)
d<-c(1,4,12,32)
df<-data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

can i simply say df$a * df$b
please help. I am getting an issue with duplication. they are getting multiplied in matrix form and there is also issue with different length columns.

Comment: Something like `df$d <- with(df, a*b)`?

Comment: Yes, I need only row elementwise multiplication

Comment: You don't need the `cbind()` calls when building data.frames; the `data.frame()` constructor function automatically takes each argument as a separate column.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Base R:

```
df$c <- df$a * df$b
```

or `df$c <- with(df, a * b)`

In Dplyr:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(c = a * b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must assign `df$a * df$b` to a new column in the dataframe.

`df$c<-df$a*df$b`

This adds a new column (`df$c`) which contains column `a` multiplied by column `b`.